# Smarty template variable carry to header.tpl

Tags: variables, smarty, whmcs

Editing the WHMCS template files (smarty) I can't seem to carry this variable outside of its tpl page and into the header.

---

**knowledgebase.tpl**

```
{assign var="page_alias" value="knowledgebase"}
```

**header.tpl**

```
{assign var="active_link" value="my value"}

{if isset($page_alias) && $page_alias == 'knowledgebase'}
  {$active_link}
{else}
  {}
{/if}
```

---

If all that is on the same page it outputs "my value". but when I have it setup on pages as described above it returns nothing. I've also tried the scope='global' at the end of the first code.

I see several people with similar questions on here but none seem to have an actual answer.

Comment: I don't know WHMCS (I don't even know what it stands for) but I suspect this is because the different templates are being parsed completely separately by the underlying PHP, so there is no way of them seeing each other's variables.

Answer (score 0):

Use session instead. I had the similar problem. Couldn't find any solution. Even contacting WHMCS support did not help! So I just used session variables to handle my job.